# opencv finding image cordinates on another image

Tags: image, opencv, find, point

How to find image "A" coordinates on image "B" which contains image "A".

I wrote this program which is only checking pixel values, does anyone know is there any library tool do this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Throwback1986 suggested, you will probably want to use [matchTemplate](http://opencv.itseez.com/modules/imgproc/doc/object_detection.html?highlight=matchtemplate#void%20matchTemplate%28InputArray%20image,%20InputArray%20temp,%20OutputArray%20result,%20int%20method%29). [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8218997/how-to-detect-the-sun-from-the-space-sky-in-opencv/8221251#8221251) is one of my answers showing how to detect the Sun from virtual spacecraft. [Here](http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/template_matching/template_matching.html#template-matching) is the newer tutorial from OpenCV on using `matchTemplate`. Now, there are some caveats for using the `matchTemplate` approach. If image "A" can be at an arbitrary pose (e.g., changes in scale, rotation, perspective, etc) in image "B", then `matchTemplate` isn't going to work very well. If that happens to be the case, you will want to use to go the feature detection route as suggested by Adrian Popovici.

Comment: thank you I would check links and tutorials. I am grateful to you for help. Your answer is most helpful for me, because of that I accept your answer. thank you for spending time to answer my question.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at the last 3 tutorials from this link: 
http://opencv.itseez.com/doc/tutorials/features2d/table_of_content_features2d/table_of_content_features2d.html

I don't think the checking of pixels is a good approach.

Comment: thank you I would check tutorials, thank you for spending time to answer my question.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider something like template matching as described in this [tutorial](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut6.html).

A more brute force approach would be to "slide" image A incrementally over image B looking for the point of least difference.  (Note that this assumes image A is some reasonably small subset of image B.)  You can use the cvNorm function to compute the [L1 norm](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/core_operations_on_arrays.html#norm), which is equivalent to computing the Sum of Squared Differences (SSD).  Use the CV_L1 option.  [Here](http://siddhantahuja.wordpress.com/tag/sum-of-squared-differences/) is a link describing the application of SSD in image correlation.

Comment: thank you I would check links, your answer helped me. I am grateful to you for help. thank you for spending time to answer my question.