# one image is a subset of another image

Tags: image, image-processing, image-comparison

The scenario is,

There are two images and we are required to say whether one image is a subset of another image. In other words, image **A** is present within or part of image **B**.

We tried to use traditional bit by bit comparison, but it looks too time consuming. 
Is there any other image comparison algorithm in place that can help us?
Thanks in advance for your responses.

Comment: Try OpenCV library.
You can find more information at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8416414/opencv-finding-image-cordinates-on-another-image

Comment: Thanks, it looks relevant. I will check with that.

Comment: More specifically look at pattern matching. There is also OpenCV tutorial for it.

Comment: Thanks for your response jnovacho. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

Check out SIFT and SURF [descriptors](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/nonfree/doc/feature_detection.html?highlight=surf#feature-detection-and-description) to find keypoints in the images, and then match them across the two images.