# Numbers/Text/Picture recognition in an Image using Java

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing, image-recognition

I'm working on an university project, I have to find and existing Java code that allows doing number recognition on a picture of a soccer t-shirt. The title is more general because the problem can be seen as number recognition, text recognition or finding a picture in a picture. I need a program that given an input image squares number in a minimum inclusion square (like OpenCV allows doing with faces) and (if possible) tells user if the number was found or not.

I tried using tesseract, aspose and many codes posted in this site, sourceforge and similar but no one was usefull. I think the easiest way is using OpenCV, maybe using a classifier or a neural network but I'm really new in this. Can someone help me linking me an implementation of my problem or in some other way? Thank you and sorry for my terrible English :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23281582/java-image-recognition, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598818/finding-a-picture-in-a-picture-with-java

Comment: For finding a library, probably the http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ is a better place. Otherwise, I would say this is a too broad question. [ask]

Comment: @GáborBakos Software Recommendations moderator here. We have fairly strict quality guidelines, so I'd appreciated it if you would link to our [question quality guidelines](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46) whenever you recommend someone re-ask a question on the site. Thanks!