# Using OpenCV to recognise similar (not completely identical) simple images?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, image-comparison

Say I have a very simple image or shape such as this stick man drawing:

[image]

I also have a library of other simple images which I want to compare the first image to and determine the closest match:

[image]

Notice that the two stick men are not completely identical but are reasonably similar.

I want to be able to compare the first image to each image in my library until a reasonably close match is found. If necessary, my image library could contain numerous variations of the same image in order to help decide which type of image I have. For example:

[image]

My question is whether this is something that OpenCV would be capable of? Has it been done before, and if so, can you point me in the direction of some examples? Many thanks for your help.

*Edit*: Through my searches I have found many examples of people who are comparing images, or even people that are comparing images which have been stretched or skewed such as this: [Checking images for similarity with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv) . Unfortunately as you can see, my images are not just translated (Rotated/Skewed/Stretched) versions of one another - They actually different images although they are very similar.

Comment: try "Scale invariant and deformation tolerant partial shape matching" by Damien Michel, Iasonas Oikonomidis and Antonis Argyros : http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0262885611000151

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do it using feature template match function of OpenCV.  You can use `matchTemplate` function to look for the feature and then, `minMaxLoc` to find its location.  Check out the tutorial on OpenCV web site for `matchTemplate`.

Comment: Does Template Matching work when the images are rotated slightly from one another? The examples in the OpenCV documentation and from searching google all seem to be using images which are orientated the same direction.

Comment: Should work for small rotation (like 5-10 degrees or so) but beyond that, it may not give very good results.

Answer (score 1):

seems you need feature points detections and matching. Check these docs from OpenCV:

http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html
http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_flann_matcher/feature_flann_matcher.html

Answer (score 1):

For your particular type of images, you might get good results by using [moments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#double%20matchShapes%28InputArray%20contour1,%20InputArray%20contour2,%20int%20method,%20double%20parameter%29)/[HuMoments](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#humoments) for the connected components (which you can find with [findContours](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=moments#findcontours)).

Answer (score 1):

since there is a rotation involved, I dont think template matching would work well. You probably need to use Feature point detection such as SIFT or SURF.

Comment: You should be careful with SURF in commercial applications since it's descriptor is patented

Comment: @iwlagn, true. I wonder how did it make it is way to be implemented in opencv?

Comment: SURF is a good algorithm and no one forbids you from implementing it or using in your research purposes. Implementing patented algorithm is no against BSD license (which is used by OpenCV). So why SURF should not be implemented in OpenCV?

Comment: @iwlagn, am not saying SURF is not a good algorithm, otherwise I won't promote it in the first place. I was wondering how a patented algorithm does not violate BSD licence which allows redistribution of binaries of opencv.

Comment: There two things here. First is BSD license, which says "do whatever you want but do not remove author information". Second is patented descriptor of SURF (algorithm is not patented as far, as I know). Nothing forbids you from IMPLEMENTING any of algorithms, no matter how many patents do they have (which is done in OpenCV). But patented algorithm can limit USE of this implementation, and this should care only OpenCV users.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: This won't work with rotation. Same for `matchTemplate`. I am yet to try the `findContours` + `moments` as in bjoernz answer which sounds promising.

*Failed Solution:*
I tried using `ShapeContextDistanceExtractor`([1](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/modules/shape/doc/shape_distances.html)) available in OpenCV 3.0 along with `findContours` on your sample images to get good results. The sample images were cropped to same size as original image(128*200). You can could as well use `resize` in OpenCV.

---

Code below compares images in `images` folder with `1.png` as the base image.

```
#include "opencv2/shape.hpp"
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

const int MAX_SHAPES = 7;

vector<Point> findContours( const Mat& compareToImg )
{
    vector<vector<Point> > contour2D;
    findContours(compareToImg, contour2D, RETR_LIST, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    //converting 2d vector contours to 1D vector for comparison
    vector <Point> contour1D;
    for (size_t border=0; border < contour2D.size(); border++) {
        for (size_t p=0; p < contour2D[border].size(); p++) {
            contour1D.push_back( contour2D[border][p] );
        }
    }

    //limiting contours size to reduce distance comparison time
    contour1D.resize( 300 );
    return contour1D;
}

int main()
{
    string path = "./images/";
    cv::Ptr <cv::ShapeContextDistanceExtractor> distanceExtractor = cv::createShapeContextDistanceExtractor();

    //base image
    Mat baseImage= imread( path + "1.png", IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

    vector<Point> baseImageContours= findContours( baseImage );

    for ( int idx = 2; idx <= MAX_SHAPES; ++idx ) {

        stringstream imgName;
        imgName << path << idx << ".png";
        Mat compareToImg=imread( imgName.str(), IMREAD_GRAYSCALE ) ;

        vector<Point> contii = findContours( compareToImg );
        float distance = distanceExtractor->computeDistance( baseImageContours, contii );

        std::cout<<" distance to " << idx << " : " << distance << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Result**

> distance to 2 : 89.7951
>    distance to 3 : 14.6793
>    distance to 4 : 6.0063
>    distance to 5 : 4.79834
>    distance to 6 : 0.0963184
>    distance to 7 : 0.00212693

Comment: Why did this solution fail?

Comment: @AlexL If you check the revision history for his answer, he says it "failed" because it doesn't work with rotations.

[For me, that's not a problem, since my images are never rotated.]

Answer (score 0):

Do three things: 1. Forget about image comparison since you really comparing stroke symbols. 2. Download and play wth a Gesture Search app from google store; 3. Realize that for good performance you cannot recognize your strokes without using timestamp information about stroke drawing. Otherwice we would have a successful handwriting recognition. Then you can research Android stroke reco library to write your code properly.