# Where do I begin to look for image matching libraries in python?

Tags: python, image, algorithm, sorting

Simply stated, I have to match images based on similarities. So if two images of different size happen to be the same, or if they differ only by watermark, they can be matched as the same.

I know python must have at least a starting implementation of this, but I cannot seem to find it. What would this be called in python-ese or imaging science?

Comment: There is a book about "Programming Computer Vision with Python" published by O'Reilly that surely must touch on some of this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try [OpenCV](http://opencv.org/) which has a Python interface.
See this question for using OpenCV to do image matching:
[Checking images for similarity with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv).