# Is there a mobile image recognition library?

Tags: c#, android, ios, .net, mobile

I want to make an application that opens up camera, point at an image and if the image is recognized in my database, give all the corresponding info, else, nothing happens. I dont know where to start, can you give me orientation and specify what cross-platform / ios / android language should I use?

Comment: Vuforia is image and object recognition library. If you just need to show some text when image is recognized, Vuforia for Android should do. If you want more interaction, like moving objects that are shown when image is recognized, you should use Vuforia for Unity and then export to Android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try OpenCV. Check for similarities to match database image and camera view. take a look at following link. similar post described there:

[Checking images for similarity with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv)