# Orienting an image in Java?

Tags: java, image-processing

In my program, I have a 2D binary array, which represents an image. I then compare my binary array to other binary arrays, to find the most similar image.

But, I have an issue with orientation. In order for a comparison to be made, they must all be oriented the same way (i.e. longest part of the image along the x axis). How would I go about finding the longest line of the shape and then orienting that along the x axis?

Comment: That sounds like a PCA problem. https://github.com/mkobos/pca_transform

Comment: have a look into this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/a/11541587/5352399

Comment: you need to add examples what shape where??