# Is there property in Tesseract OCR to find string and delete page from PDF

Tags: node.js, ocr, tesseract, pdftk, pdf.js

I was trying to convert Image PDF to text PDF in Tesseract OCR. In between i need to check for cover page and remove that from the result. Is it possible in Tessaract OCR itself to identify cover page based on specific properties of cover page(cover page text matching). or do i have to take the whole output of tessetact OCR result and provide my logic to scan PDF and remove cover page. I am fully confused and any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Theres no way for Tesseract to do that, you should remove the page beforehand, and then hand the PDF image to OCR.

There's a good answer on how to do what i told you at https://stackoverflow.com/a/11541587/9740486

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try out