# Scanning through camera against a bank of 10 images

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I building an app that can use an iPad camera to scan for particular images. There will be a bank of 10 images that will be matched against, and when there is a match on one I need to navigate the app to a specific screen.

I guess you can compare this to a QR scanner, but without QR codes.

Example of one of the images to scan is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/EN58Z.jpg

Trouble is, I'm struggling to come up with a solution to scan the images. The other parts, no issue.

I've tried pattern markers with a-frame, I've done a load of research but can't find anything concrete at the moment.

Any direction will greatly be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to import some machine-learning library and if it's text only extract the text and match it to a dictionary:

https://github.com/zsajjad/react-native-text-detector

Or you could match for similar images with opencv:

[Checking images for similarity with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv)

https://github.com/brainhubeu/react-native-opencv-tutorial