# Check if two already loaded webp images are equal with javascript

Tags: javascript, webp

I have two webp images on my page and want to check if they are equal without sending any ajax requests to the server. Note that image file names are different each time. So need to check that manually with javascript using a library. Any heads up or link would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Can you share a snippet?

Comment: what do you mean by "equal", is it equal filename or equal pixel values ?

Comment: @DhananjaiPai it means if the two images are the same.

Comment: Again, same as in the pixels are the same, or all attributes of the images are the same - like filename, type etc ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv You can use openCV.js to try the above methods from browser

Comment: @DhananjaiPai no file names are different and maybe the extension too

Comment: Then it can be very challenging since different extensions would be storing the "same" image in very different "formats", causing a problem with comparisons. Using openCV.js could help you convert them to a common pixel representation and find the diff

Comment: @DhananjaiPai thanks mate but dont know how to run openCV on browsers I think we cant