# How to measure the similarity between a whole group of images?

Tags: image, image-processing, comparison, artificial-intelligence, similarity

I need to compare the similarity between images inside different groups. I know that there are ways to evaluate the similarity between 2 images (e.g. https://github.com/richzhang/PerceptualSimilarity).

But I have 2 different groups with 100 images each and I need to compare the inner similarity of both. What is the best way of doing that?

Comment: What do you mean by inner similarity?

Comment: Have a look at [the various solutions provided here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv)

Comment: @KavinduRavishka I meant to evaluate how close one is to the other