# How can i compare 2 images java opencv?

Tags: java, android-studio, opencv

I need to compare 2 photo. I used opencv and find objects and highlight them with rectangles. What algorithms should I use to compare pictures next? I need to find out how similar these pictures are to each other.

```
    Mat src = new Mat();
    Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp, src);
    Mat gray = new Mat();
    org.opencv.core.Size size = new org.opencv.core.Size(3,3);
    Imgproc.GaussianBlur(src, gray, size, 30, 30);
    Imgproc.cvtColor( src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2BGR);
    Imgproc.cvtColor( src, src, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
    Imgproc.Canny(src, gray, 10, 10);
    List<MatOfPoint> contours = new ArrayList<>();
    Mat hierarchy = new Mat();
    Imgproc.findContours(gray, contours, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_LIST, 
    Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE);
    double maxVal = 0;
    int maxValIdx = 0;
    int maxIdx = 0;
    double maxRectTL = 0;
    double maxRectBR = 0;
    org.opencv.core.Point rectTL = new org.opencv.core.Point();
    org.opencv.core.Point rectBR = new Point();

    Mat out = new Mat();
    //Core.extractChannel(gray, src, 0);
    for (int contourIdx = 0; contourIdx < contours.size(); contourIdx++) {
        Log.d("qwert","size: " + index +": "+ contours.get(contourIdx).t());
        Imgproc.drawContours(src,contours,contourIdx,new Scalar(0,0,255),-1);
        org.opencv.core.Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(maxValIdx));
        Imgproc.rectangle(src, rect.tl(), rect.br(), Scalar.all(Color.GREEN),2);
        //org.opencv.core.Rect rect = Imgproc.boundingRect(contours.get(contourIdx));
        if(maxRectBR < rect.br().x * rect.br().y){
            maxRectBR = rect.br().x * rect.br().y;
            maxIdx = contourIdx;
            rectBR = rect.br();
            rectTL = rect.tl();

        }

        double contourArea = Imgproc.contourArea(contours.get(contourIdx));
        if(maxVal  < contourArea) {
            maxVal = contourArea;
            maxValIdx = contourIdx;
        }
    }

    Bitmap tempBmp1 = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(), 
    bmp.getConfig());
    Utils.matToBitmap(src, tempBmp1);
    if(index == 0){
        im_first.setImageBitmap(tempBmp1);
    }else{
        im_second.setImageBitmap(tempBmp1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Checking images for similarity with OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541154/checking-images-for-similarity-with-opencv)

Comment: Yes, but how can I used it on java? Library numpy dont have on the java. C++ or python as I know.